# Implementations of Subspace JavaScript cross-domain communication?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, cross-domain

This [pdf paper](http://www2007.org/papers/paper801.pdf) describes a way to manage cross-domain communication using JavaScript with a bit of help from the server.

Does anyone have experience with this approach?  I know [CrossSafe](http://groups.google.com/group/crosssafe) has an implementation, but it's pretty quiet over there.  (NSFW spam in that group.)

While we're here, does anyone know of a good flash bridge?  I'm OK with crossdomain.xml as a solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

That link did not point to a pdf paper. It linked to some guys profile with a bunch of links.

If you want to do cross domain communication you have two main choices: Serverside proxy or a JSON call.

Eric

Comment: Edited to have the correct link.  But no, those aren't the only two options, as explained in that research paper.  I'm aware of proxy and JSON, and the reason I asked about Subspace is because it *is* a working alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check out easyXDM (http://easyxdm.net). Its extremely easy to use and has some nifty features, for example, check out http://consumer.easyxdm.net/example/methods.html.
Its works for all browser using the best available technique (postMessage, fragment)